# can someone help me with this error?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have this error and I don't know what error is that, I'm newbie here. Thank you in advance.

syntax error, unexpected '', '' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT tbl_input.* FROM tbl_input";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
?>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: 
            [
            <?php
            while ($qry = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $date = $qry['m_date'];
                $name = $qry['comp_name'];
                $id = $qry['id'];

                $end = new DateTime($schedule);
                $Edate = date_format($end, "d");
                $Emonth = date_format($end, "n");
                $Eyear = date_format($end, "Y");
                $emonth = $Emonth - 1;
```

somewhere in this line I have an error:

```
                echo'
                {
                    title: "'. $name . '",
                    start: new Date('.$Eyear.', '.$emonth', '.$Edate.')
                },
                ';
            }
            ?>
            ]
        });

    });

</script>
</head>

    <div id='calendar'></div>
<?php
include('./inc/footer.inc')
?>
```

Comment: What "this line"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you missed a `.` in `$emonth`

Change

```
start: new Date('.$Eyear.', '.$emonth', '.$Edate.')
```

to

```
 start: new Date('.$Eyear.', '.$emonth.', '.$Edate.')
```

Comment: @DrkWhz24: accept the answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: oh yes, it says I can accept an answer in 8 mins haha :D anyway, thanks again, appreciate it.

Comment: no issues, that's what stackoverflow is for... @DrkWhz24